# Running codeigniter in another framework (octobercms)

Tags: codeigniter-3, octobercms

I'm running octobercms for pages and i need to run codeigniter views inside the pages.

My structure at the moment is:

```
 -ocotbercms folders
 -octobercms root files (artisan, index.php, etc..)
 -external.php
 -codeigniter folder called "ci"
  -application (codeigniter)
  -system (codeigniter)
  -index.php (codeigniter)
```

I'm able to get codeigniter instance via external.php file but all i get is a codeigniter 404 page.

external.php content:

```
<?php
// Remove the query string
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
// Include the codeigniter framework
define("REQUEST", "external");
ob_start();
require('./ci/index.php');
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

October cms page getting instance:

```
<?php
function onStart()
{
    require('external.php');
    $ci =& get_instance();
}
?>
```

How can i run my codeigniter app in octobercms page? I've read cjax documentation but didn't understand how to implement inside octobercms page. Any other solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hmm. why would like to do that exactly?

Comment: Please don't do that, if really you have to do that, expose an API from your old codeigniter code